Google Chrome - "Save as PDF" font is not dark enough when HTML page is in Dark Mode
Here's the original page (It's in Dark Mode. Either Google Chrome or X is in Dark Mode, not sure which):

Here's what it looks like when I select the text in the original page and choose Print > Save as PDF (se:

The font in the PDF is very light in color. So it looks like it took the color from the original HTML.
If you know of a way to make the font black in color, please share.

The only good way to edit a PDF is in an editor (up to a point). So we can easily remove any blackgrounds to just have the text. But then it may be laborious to edit every letter group. Thus we can use a coherent cpdf command line for that.

cpdf -blacktext "Reproducible Success Strategies _ Luca Dellanna.pdf" -o blackout.pdf


